# ラッパーライブラリの配置

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

unmanagedなC++ DllをC#側から使うため、C++/CLIでラッパーライブラリを作成しました。
C#側から、とりあえずTestプロジェクトを作成して動作を確認しようと試みたのですが、ライブラリの読み込みに失敗してしましました。

Testプロジェクトのビルド出力フォルダにはラッパーライブラリのコピーが作成されるのですが、
UnmanagedのDllはコピーされないことが原因のようです。
この場合、プロジェクトの設定はどのように設定するのが良いのでしょうか？

実行環境はVisualStudio2013 Comunity
UnmanagedなDllもソースコードからソリューションに登録しています。

Comment: [プロジェクトでローカル データ ファイルを管理する](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms246989.aspx)が使えるかと思ったのですが、C++プロジェクトでは無効となっていますね。[ビルドイベント](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx)でコピーするという手もあります。

Answer (score 1):

1つの方法として、C#プロジェクトとC++/CLIプロジェクトの双方で出力ディレクトリを同じ場所にするというものがあります。私は、ソリューション内のすべてのプロジェクトで出力ディレクトリを`$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)`や`$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)-$(PlatformShortName)`に統一することをよくやります。